# fabric:profile-refresh and fabric:watch doesn't work with Fuse 6.3

Tags: redhat, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fabric8

I'm using Jboss Fuse 6.3. I have created a fabric environment with 2 child container. I have assigned one test profile to one of the container. I'm trying to refresh my profile as I have to updated some of the bundles which are part of my test profile.

To do this I login to fabric console and executed **fabric:profile-refresh test-profile**

But when I see the bundle's header **Bnd-LastModified** then it seems not updated and referring the old one only.

I tried with **fabric:watch *** command as well but no luck.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Following is my configuration in **io.fabric8.agent.properties**

`org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories = <remote-repository>`
`org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.globalUpdatePolicy = always`

Comment: which kind of artifacts are those? SNAPSHOT or released ones?

Comment: Those are just simple OSGI bundles with rest endpoints

Comment: SNAPSHOT or released ones?

Comment: My osgi bundles are released only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:
 If your bundle is non-SNAPSHOT then there's no attempt to fetch "newer" released version. For maven each non-SNAPSHOT is immutable.

Longer answer:
If by *I have to updated some of the bundles* you mean `mvn clean install` new version to your `~/.m2/repository`, then it should be picked up by Fuse - assuming that `~/.m2/repository` is one of your *default repositories* - please check `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn` PID, `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.defaultRepositories` property.

If however you want Fuse to download newer version of non-SNAPSHOT artifact from some remote repository (Nexus, Artifactory, ...), then a version in *local repository* is preferred. By default, in Fuse 6.3, this *local repository* is in `$FUSE_HOME/data/repository`. There's special option in `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn` PID called `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.updateReleases` that allows you to set *non canonical* Maven behavior to actually update non-SNAPSHOTs.

In fabric mode (which you're using) it's a bit more complex.

There is fabric-agent configuration of maven resolver in `io.fabric8.agent` PID and `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.*` properties - their meaning is the same as `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn` PID and `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.*` properties in standalone mode.

In order to verify how Maven resolution works, you can uncomment these log settings in `karaf` profile:

```
# help with identification of maven-related problems with fabric-maven
#log4j.logger.org.eclipse.aether = TRACE
#log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers = DEBUG
#log4j.logger.io.fabric8.maven.util = TRACE
#log4j.logger.io.fabric8.maven.url = TRACE
#log4j.logger.io.fabric8.agent.download = DEBUG
```

Also please read my articles about pax-url-aether and Maven in general:

- http://ggrzybek.blogspot.com/2016/07/using-maven-with-osgi-part-1.html
- http://ggrzybek.blogspot.com/2016/07/using-maven-with-osgi-part-2.html
- http://ggrzybek.blogspot.com/2016/10/using-maven-with-osgi-part-3.html

Comment: Yes. Make sense. Thanks for sharing this valuable info.